# Jenkins, Selenium, C #, MSBuild

Tags: c#, selenium, msbuild

I have met a very big difficulty to Build my C# Selenium
Test in Jenkins. I am new with both - Selenium and Jenkins.

**My Paths:**

```
"C:\Users\Bobby\source\repos\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\nuget.exe" restore "C:\Users\Bobby\source\repos\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers.sln"

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers.sln

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe/testcontainer:"C:\Users\Bobby\source\repos\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\bin\Debug\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers.exe"
```

**My Console Output it is the following:**

> MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch:
>   /testcontainer:C:\Users\Bobby\source\repos\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\bin\Debug\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers.exe
>
> For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers>exit 1  Build
>   marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

My Question is how to deal with that? I have read and tried everything mention already, but without success. Please, orientate me.

Answer (score 0):

`/testcontainer` is an argument of [MSTest.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#testcontainer), not of `MSBuild.exe`, so last line becomes:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSTest.exe/testcontainer:"C:\Users\Bobby\source\repos\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers\bin\Debug\SeleniumTestMultipleBrowsers.exe"
```